# Form not submitting after inserting form into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Upon submitting a braintree payment form, I use .html() to replace the old form and insert a new one. The form is inserted properly but when I fill it out and hit submit, nothing happens.  There is no activity in the server logs or Chrome developer tools (in Network or Console tabs). Any help on why this is the case / what the issue is would be great. Thanks!

Braintree form:

```
<div id="braintree_<%= order.id %>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Payment for <%= order.name %></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="braintree_body_<%= order.id %>">
<%= render 'orders/order_cc_charge', order: order %>
<% total = order.projected_total %>
<% if order.payments.present? %>
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th>Payment $</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </thead>
    <% order.payments.each do |payment| %>
    <% total -= payment.amount %>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(payment.amount) %></td>
        <td><%= payment.notes %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(total) %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
  <%= form_tag create_transaction_url, remote: true, id: "braintree-payment-form_#{order.id}" do %>
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"> <i class="fa fa-usd"> </i> </span>
      <%= text_field_tag :amount, total.round(2), class: "input-small" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :order_id, order.id %>
    </div>
      <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" placeholder="Card #" />
      <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" class="input-mini" placeholder="CVV" />
    <p>
      <label class="inline bold">Expiration Date</label>
      <input type="text" size="2" name="month" class="input-small" placeholder="Month (MM)" /> / <input type="text" size="4" name="year" class="input-small" placeholder="Year (20XX)" />
    </p>
    <%= text_area_tag :notes, nil, placeholder: "Notes", class: "span10" %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" id="braintree_footer_<%= order.id %>">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Payment</button>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
  var braintree = Braintree.create('<%= j(ENV['CSE_KEY']) %>');
  braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form_<%= order.id %>');
</script>
</div>

<script>
  $('#braintree_<%= order.id %>').on('show', function () {
    $("#trucks_refresh").remove();
  });
  $('#braintree_<%= order.id %>').on('hide', function () {
    if ($("#trucks_refresh").length) {
    }
    else {
      $(document.body).append('<%= j(render 'deliveries/trucks_refresh_btn') %>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Controller action:

```
def create_transaction
  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    :amount => params[:amount],
    :credit_card => {
      :number => params[:number],
      :cvv => params[:cvv],
      :expiration_month => params[:month],
      :expiration_year => params[:year]
    },
    :options => {
      :submit_for_settlement => true
    }
  )

  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  if result.success?
    @payment = Payment.create(order_id: @order.id, amount: params[:amount], date_received: Date.today, job_id: @order.job_id, client_id: @order.client_id, method: "2", notes: params[:notes])
    "<h1>Success! Transaction ID: #{result.transaction.id}</h1>"
  else
    "<h1>Error: #{result.message}</h1>"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

JS action:

```
$("#braintree_<%= @order.id %>").html('<%= j(render 'deliveries/braintree_modal_body', order: @order) %>');
```

Comment: what Server side programming language are you working on?

Comment: I'm using Ruby on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the form all within 1 div and now the form works fine.  I guess splitting the form within 2 different divs was not allowing the submit button to submit the form properly after the initial submission.

```
<%= form_tag create_transaction_url, remote: true, id: "braintree-payment-form_#{order.id}" do %>
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"> <i class="fa fa-usd"> </i> </span>
      <%= text_field_tag :amount, total.round(2), class: "input-small" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :order_id, order.id %>
    </div>
      <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" placeholder="Card #" class="input-medium" />
      <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" class="input-mini" placeholder="CVV" />
      <input type="text" size="2" name="month" class="input-small" placeholder="Month (MM)" /> / <input type="text" size="4" name="year" class="input-small" placeholder="Year (20XX)" />
    <%= text_area_tag :notes, nil, placeholder: "Notes", class: "span12" %>
    <%= button_tag "Submit Payment", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large", type:"submit", id:"submit" %>
  <% end %>
<script>
  var braintree = Braintree.create('<%= j(ENV['CSE_KEY']) %>');
  braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form_<%= order.id %>');
</script>
```